# How do I make these links go horizontally and not vertically?

Tags: php, css

this is what the links look like: http://www.screencast.com/users/rockstarvisible/folders/Jing/media/6d18eddb-4785-459e-88a5-b6448a5771ef

the css file can be found on rankingclimber.com/css/style.css

### this is the code in the footer.php file:

`

```
    <h3>Website Links</h3>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="what-is-ranking-climber.php">What is Ranking Climber?</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
        <li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="press.php">Press</a></li>
        <li><a href="terms.php">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
        <li><a href="privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    </ul>
```

### `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People are all over the place with their answers..

The `<ul>` and `<li>` elements are naturally block level elements... meaning unless a proper width is set, they will take up the entire width of the 'line' they exist on...

Your `<ul>` could remain block level if you want (usually very helpful) so you **do not** want to apply `display : inline` to your `<ul>` ...

...

You *could use*:

```
li {
    display : inline;
}
```

which will turn your `<li>` into 'inline' elements--but you lose the versatility of block level elements (custom width/height, floats, etc) thus the more common alternative is to use:

```
li {
   float : left;
}
```

And you'll probably want to make sure the padding/margins are set to your aesthetic needs, for example:

```
li {
   float : left;
   padding : 0;
   margin : 0 0 0 12px; // 12px left margin, for some breathing room
}
```

If you don't specify a width, a floated block will shrink to the width (give or take a few pixels) of its content... which is handy knowledge for creating 'tabs.'

Hopefully this clears up any confusion within this question.  See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/X3hAZ/ (I added a black border so you can see the dimensions of each block.)

Comment: Thanks Julian. I loved your example. Your tip about the width was the key to fixing this. I changed the width from 215 to 1060. That along with your other advice really helped. Thanks for taking the time to explain this to me and teach me something. I really appreciate it man.

Answer (score 2):

In the css give

display: inline;
float:left

I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
ul{
    display:inline;
}
```

in your css file.

Comment: It shouldn't be applied to the `<ul>` -- that will turn the `<ul>` element into an inline element... doing nothing for the `<li>`.  This answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

add the property

```
li { float: left; }
```

to your css

Answer (score 0):

@Pawan :- If you are using css then u can write the code given below:

```
ul li {
    float:left;
}
```

Hope it works............

Answer (score 0):

Put ul{margin:0; padding:0} for the ul. Then put {display:inline; padding:0; margin:0} for li... So complete code is `ul{margin:0;padding:0;}
li{display:inline; padding:0; margin:0;` I think this should do the trick.
[Here is a good example of this, complete with a css hover effect](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic55647.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
ul{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
li{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   display: inline;
}
```

hope this will work.

Comment: Your second `<ul>` should be a `<li>` -- and your `float : left` is a pointless operator on 'inline' elements...